# Can't perform a search on a DatabaseView using Android Room Persistence LIbrary

Tags: android, android-room

Hi Android Developers,

I am trying to use the new version of Android Room to create a DatabaseView and perform a search on the DBView, but the DAO cannot find any results, even when I type pretty obvious queries.

Here is the version of my Room Gradle dependencies.

```
  //Android Room
def room_version = "2.1.0-alpha04"
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

Here is my DatabaseView

```
@DatabaseView("SELECT  * from popular UNION SELECT * from trending UNION SELECT * from favorite",
        viewName = "searchView")
data class SeriesEntity(
        @PrimaryKey
        var id: Int? = null,
        var originalName: String? = null,
        var name: String? = null,
        var popularity: Double? = null,
        var voteCount: Int? = null,
        var voteAverage: Double? = null,
        var firstAirDate: String? = null,
        var posterPath: String? = null,
        var genreIds: List<Int>? = null,
        var originalLanguage: String? = null,
        var backdropPath: String? = null,
        var overview: String? = null,
        var originCountry: List<String>? = null
)
```

Here is my DAO:

```
    @Dao
interface SearchSeriesDao {
    @Query("""
        SELECT * FROM searchView WHERE name MATCH :query """)
    fun query(query : String) : LiveData<List<SeriesEntity>>
}
```

My main Database class:

```
@Database(entities =
    arrayOf(
        FavoritesEntity::class,
        PopularEntity::class,
        TrendingEntity::class),
        views = arrayOf(SeriesEntity::class), version = 5)
```

Every time that I try to use my DAO to search for a simple record in my view, the LiveData returned is empty.